# Как убирать/добавлять класс при динамическом добавлении контента?

Tags: javascript

Столкнулся с такой проблемой.
Есть определенный контент, при котором при клике я добавляю и удаляю класс active. Весь такой код у меня работает.
Но когда я добавляю динамически ещё контент, то класс к нему добавляется, но не удаляется.
Подскажите как можно это решить?

CodePen: https://codepen.io/Power2021/pen/qBXQEbK?editors=1010.

```js
const btn = document.querySelector('.btn');
const inputText = document.querySelector('.input-text');
const InputNumber = document.querySelector('.input-number');
const wrap = document.querySelector('.wrap');
const wrapItem = document.querySelectorAll('.wrap__item');

// Создаём элементы
btn.addEventListener('click', () => {
  const inputTextValue = inputText.value;
  const InputNumberValue = InputNumber.value;

  let item = `
    <div class="wrap__item">
      <div class="wrap__item-name">${inputTextValue}</div>
      <div class="wrap__item-cena">${InputNumberValue}</div>
    </div>
  `

  wrap.insertAdjacentHTML('beforeend', item);

})

// Добавление/Удаление active
wrap.addEventListener('click', (e) => {
  const target = e.target;
  const targetItem = target.closest('.wrap__item');
  if (targetItem) {
    for (let i = 0; i < wrapItem.length; i++) {
      wrapItem[i].classList.remove('active');
    }
    target.closest('.wrap__item').classList.add('active');
  }
});
```

```css
* {
  margin: 0;
  padding: 0;
}

.container {
  max-width: 900px;
  margin: 0 auto;
  padding: 0 15px;
}

.add {
  border: 2px solid #000;
  margin-top: 20px;
  padding: 20px;
}

.wrap {
  margin-top: 20px;
}

.wrap__item {
  max-width: 100px;
  position: relative;
  cursor: pointer;
}

.wrap__item:not(:last-child) {
  margin-bottom: 20px;
}

.wrap__item.active::before {
  content: "";
  width: 10px;
  height: 10px;
  border-radius: 100%;
  background-color: #000;
  position: absolute;
  top: 50%;
  right: 0;
}
```

```html
<div class="container">
  <div class="add">
    <h1>Добавляем что-то</h1>
    <input class="input input-text" type="text" placeholder="Названия">
    <input class="input input-number" type="number" placeholder="Цена">
    <button class="btn">Добавить</button>
  </div>

  <div class="wrap">
    <div class="wrap__item active">
      <div class="wrap__item-name">Пункт</div>
      <div class="wrap__item-cena">22</div>
    </div>

    <div class="wrap__item">
      <div class="wrap__item-name">Пункт</div>
      <div class="wrap__item-cena">555</div>
    </div>

    <div class="wrap__item">
      <div class="wrap__item-name">Пункт</div>
      <div class="wrap__item-cena">22222</div>
    </div>
  </div>
</div>
```

Answer (score 1):

Вообще можно было бы сделать по другому, добавлять новые `input type="radio"` и не нужно будет писать некоторую логику, которая есть у radio кнопок.
Я переписал ваш код на класс, может что-то интересное увидите у меня

```js
class Wrap {
  wrapItemCollection = [];
  wrapNode = null;

  constructor({
    initialWrapItems,
    selectorWrap,
    selectorForm,
    selectorInputText,
    selectorInputNumber,
    selectorWrapItem
  }) {
    const form = document.querySelector(selectorForm);
    const inputTextNode = form.querySelector(selectorInputText);
    const inputNumberNode = form.querySelector(selectorInputNumber);
    this.wrapNode = document.querySelector(selectorWrap);

    this.createContentInWrapNode(initialWrapItems, this.wrapNode);
    this.addEventListenerForm(form, inputTextNode, inputNumberNode);
  }

  addEventListenerForm(form, inputTextNode, inputNumberNode) {
    form.addEventListener("submit", (event) => {
      event.preventDefault();

      const inputTextValue = inputTextNode.value;
      const InputNumberValue = inputNumberNode.value;

      const wrapItemNode = this.createWrapItemNode({
        name: inputTextValue,
        price: Number(InputNumberValue)
      });
      this.insertWrapItemIntoWrap(wrapItemNode, this.wrapNode);
      this.addEventListenerForWrapItem(wrapItemNode);

    });
  }

  createContentInWrapNode(initialWrapItems, wrapNode) {
    for (const wrapItemObj of initialWrapItems) {
      const wrapItemNode = this.createWrapItemNode(wrapItemObj);
      this.insertWrapItemIntoWrap(wrapItemNode, wrapNode);
      this.addEventListenerForWrapItem(wrapItemNode);
    }
  }

  createWrapItemNode({
    name,
    price,
    active
  }) {
    const wrapItemNode = document.createElement("div");
    wrapItemNode.classList.add("wrap__item");
    if (active === true) {
      wrapItemNode.classList.add('active');
    }
    wrapItemNode.innerHTML = `
            <div class="wrap__item-name">${name}</div>
            <div class="wrap__item-price">${price}</div>
        `;
    return wrapItemNode;
  }

  insertWrapItemIntoWrap(wrapItemNode, wrapNode) {
    wrapNode.append(wrapItemNode);
    this.wrapItemCollection.push(wrapItemNode);
  }

  addEventListenerForWrapItem(wrapItemNode) {
    wrapItemNode.addEventListener('click', (e) => {
      this.wrapItemCollection.forEach((item) => item.classList.remove("active"));
      wrapItemNode.classList.add("active");
    });
  }
}

new Wrap({
  initialWrapItems: [{
      name: "Пункт 1",
      price: 11,
      active: false
    },
    {
      name: "Пункт 2",
      price: 22,
      active: false
    },
    {
      name: "Пункт 3",
      price: 33,
      active: true
    },
  ],
  selectorWrap: '.wrap',
  selectorForm: '#form',
  selectorInputNumber: '.input-number',
  selectorInputText: '.input-text',
  selectorWrapItem: '.wrap__item'
});
```

```css
* {
  margin: 0;
  padding: 0;
}

.container {
  max-width: 900px;
  margin: 0 auto;
  padding: 0 15px;
}

.add {
  border: 2px solid #000;
  margin-top: 20px;
  padding: 20px;
}

.wrap {
  margin-top: 20px;
}

.wrap__item {
  max-width: 100px;
  position: relative;
  cursor: pointer;
}

.wrap__item:not(:last-child) {
  margin-bottom: 20px;
}

.wrap__item.active::before {
  content: "";
  width: 10px;
  height: 10px;
  border-radius: 100%;
  background-color: #000;
  position: absolute;
  top: 50%;
  right: 0;
}

.wrap__item-name {
  font-size: 1.5em;
}
```

```html
<div class="container">
  <div class="add">
    <h1>Добавляем что-то</h1>
    <form id="form" class="form">
      <input class="input input-text" type="text" placeholder="Названия" required>
      <input class="input input-number" type="number" placeholder="Цена" required>
      <button type="submit" class="btn">Добавить</button>
    </form>
  </div>

  <div class="wrap">
  </div>
</div>
```

Comment: Спасибо за ответ. Для меня ещё этот код сложно понять. Так как с классами ещё не знаком. Но Ваш код по изучаю.

Answer (score 0):

```
//const wrapItem = document.querySelectorAll('.wrap__item');
...
wrap.addEventListener('click', (e) => {
  const target = e.target;
  const targetItem = target.closest('.wrap__item');
  if (targetItem) {
    const wrapItem = document.querySelectorAll('.wrap__item'); // <---
    for (let i = 0; i < wrapItem.length; i++) {
      wrapItem[i].classList.remove('active');
    }
    target.closest('.wrap__item').classList.add('active');
  }
});
```

Comment: Спасибо за ответ. Очень помогли. Но у меня возник вопрос. Почему когда константа wrapItem в самом обработчике код работает? Но когда я её выношу в глобальную видимость, то уже код перестаёт работать?

Comment: @Alex вы сами на свой вопрос ответили. В глобальной области видимости выполняется 1 раз, а в обработчике на каждое событие.